# Creating Python objects in C++ PyTorch

Tags: python, c++, pytorch

I have trouble with creating appropriate types for my inference in C++.
I have custom class like

```py
class CustomClass:
    def __init__(self, tensor1: torch.Tensor, tensor2: torch.Tensor):
        self.tensor1 = tensor1
        self.tensor2 = tensor2

    def print(self):
        print(self.tensor1)
        print(self.tensor2)
        tensor3 = self.tensor1 + self.tensor2
        print(tensor3)
```

And i want to take object of this class as a parameter in forward function of my Model

```py
class Model(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Model, self).__init__()

    def forward(self, custom_class: CustomClass):
        custom_class.print()
```

but after i

```
    jitted = torch.jit.script(model)
    jitted.save("model.pt")
```

and try to load it and run in C++

```cpp
    torch::jit::script::Module model;
    try {
        model = torch::jit::load(MODEL, torch::kCUDA);
        model.eval();
    } catch (const c10::Error& e) {
        fmt::print("{}\n", e.what());
    }

    std::vector<torch::jit::IValue> inputs_model;

    std::vector<torch::Tensor> tensors;

    inputs_model.push_back(tensors);

    auto warmup_output = model.forward(inputs_model);
```

Where `MODEL` is `target_compile_definitions(${TARGET} PUBLIC MODEL="/model.pt")` in CMake i get of course type exception like

```
C++ exception with description "forward() Expected a value of type '__torch__.CustomClass (of Python compilation unit at: 0xb80611a0)' for argument 'custom_class' but instead found type 'List[Tensor]'.
```

I tried already exporting to C++ some kind of function to create this `CustomClass` object in C++.

```py
def create_custom_model(tensor1: torch.Tensor, tensor2: torch.Tensor):
    return CustomClass(tensor1, tensor2)

jitted = torch.jit.script(create_custom_model)
jitted.save("custom_class.pt")
```

But then there is an difference in `Python Compilation unit` like

```
C++ exception with description "forward() Expected a value of type '__torch__.CustomClass (of Python compilation unit at: 0xb9f10640)' for argument 'custom_class' but instead found type '__torch__.CustomClass (of Python compilation unit at: 0xb8345e80)'.
```

My best workaround was to create model taking tensors in forward like

```py
class TensorModel(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(TensorModel, self).__init__()
        self.model = Model()

    def forward(self, tensor1: torch.Tensor, tensor2: torch.Tensor):
        custom_class = CustomClass(tensor1, tensor2)
        self.model(custom_class)
```

and then passing it like

```cpp
    torch::jit::script::Module model;
    try {
        model = torch::jit::load(MODEL, torch::kCUDA);
        model.eval();
    } catch (const c10::Error& e) {
        fmt::print("{}\n", e.what());
    }

    std::vector<torch::jit::IValue> inputs_model;
    auto tensor1 = torch::ones({3, 3}, options);
    inputs_model.emplace_back(tensor1);

    auto tensor2 = torch::ones({3, 3}, options);
    inputs_model.emplace_back(tensor2);

    auto warmup_output = model.forward(inputs_model);
```

where `options` is like  `auto options = torch::TensorOptions().device(torch::kCUDA);`
But is there a way to create This `__torch__.CustomClass` object in C++ and pass to forward method in more C++ way?

I'm trying on Python 3.8, torch 1.10.1 and libtorch-cxx11-abi-shared-with-deps-1.10.1+cu113 with G++ 9.3 on Linux working with CLion/PyCharm